# Loop only over the 5 days not hourly open weatherAPI

Tags: php, openweathermap

I'm trying to display data from the open weather api and I've successfully consumed the api and outputted some data from it. However, the API I'm consuming is giving me hourly data. But I only want the first dataset from all 5 days within the API response.

I looped over all the fields that I want, but it's giving me every field within the past 3 hours. I only want the fields for the 5 days. (It should give me 5 results but gives me results hourly for all 5 days)

So my question is how can I only get 5 days worth of results from looping over the API response instead of grabbing everything from it hourly?
Here is my code:

```js
$currentjson_string = file_get_contents("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Shanghai&appid=&units=imperial");
$forecastjson_string = file_get_contents("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Shanghai&appid=&units=imperial");

$currentParsed = json_decode($currentjson_string, true);
$forecastParsed = json_decode($forecastjson_string, true);


// City Variables

$country = $currentParsed['name'];
$city = $currentParsed['sys']['country'];

// Current Weather Variables

$currentWeatherLongitude = $currentParsed['coord']['lon'];
$currentWeatherLatitude = $currentParsed['coord']['lat'];
$currentIcon = $currentParsed['weather'][0]['icon'];
$currentWeatherF = $currentParsed['main']['temp'];
$currentWeatherconditions = $currentParsed['weather'][0]['description'];
// F to C
$currentWeatherC = ($currentWeatherF - 32) * 5 / 9;
$currentWeathermin = $currentParsed['main']['temp_min'];
$currentWeathermax = $currentParsed['main']['temp_max'];

<div class="weather-info">
<div class="weather-centered-box">
<span class="weather-description" style="font-size:40px;"><center><?php echo $country . ', ' . $city ?></center></span>
<span class="current-conditions">Current Conditions</span> 
<span class="weather-conditions"><center><?php echo ucwords($currentWeatherconditions) ?></center></span>
<span class="weather-location" style="font-size:24px;"><?php echo 'Latitude ' . $currentWeatherLatitude . ', Longitude ' . $currentWeatherLongitude ?></span>
<span class="weather-icon"><center><?php echo '<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'.$currentIcon.'.png" />'; ?></center></span>

<?php

echo '<span class="weather-temp-f">'.$currentWeatherF.' <sup>&deg;</sup>F ('.round($currentWeatherC, 2).' <sup>&deg;</sup>C)</span>';

foreach ($forecastParsed['list'] as $key) {
  

// This is where im stuck. I don't want all the temperatures only 5 days worth of results from the temperature not hourly?
 echo $key['main']['temp'];

?>
```

JSON Response from API:

```js
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0042,
    "cnt": 39,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1551927600,
            "main": {
                "temp": 53.04,
                "temp_min": 51.65,
                "temp_max": 53.04,
                "pressure": 1027.25,
                "sea_level": 1027.25,
                "grnd_level": 1026.28,
                "humidity": 64,
                "temp_kf": 0.77
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "02d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 8
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 15.59,
                "deg": 18.5008
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 03:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1551938400,
            "main": {
                "temp": 54.28,
                "temp_min": 53.24,
                "temp_max": 54.28,
                "pressure": 1026.29,
                "sea_level": 1026.29,
                "grnd_level": 1025.32,
                "humidity": 56,
                "temp_kf": 0.58
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 801,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "few clouds",
                    "icon": "02d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 20
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 13.56,
                "deg": 20.0005
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 06:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1551949200,
            "main": {
                "temp": 49.8,
                "temp_min": 49.11,
                "temp_max": 49.8,
                "pressure": 1026.22,
                "sea_level": 1026.22,
                "grnd_level": 1025.34,
                "humidity": 54,
                "temp_kf": 0.39
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 64
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 11.74,
                "deg": 28.0067
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 09:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1551960000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 41.05,
                "temp_min": 40.71,
                "temp_max": 41.05,
                "pressure": 1027,
                "sea_level": 1027,
                "grnd_level": 1026.12,
                "humidity": 70,
                "temp_kf": 0.19
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 801,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "few clouds",
                    "icon": "02n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 24
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 9.89,
                "deg": 38.5044
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 12:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1551970800,
            "main": {
                "temp": 35.75,
                "temp_min": 35.75,
                "temp_max": 35.75,
                "pressure": 1027.53,
                "sea_level": 1027.53,
                "grnd_level": 1026.67,
                "humidity": 90,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 802,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "scattered clouds",
                    "icon": "03n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 48
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 6.4,
                "deg": 26.001
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 15:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1551981600,
            "main": {
                "temp": 34.54,
                "temp_min": 34.54,
                "temp_max": 34.54,
                "pressure": 1026.13,
                "sea_level": 1026.13,
                "grnd_level": 1025.29,
                "humidity": 94,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 64
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 3.62,
                "deg": 25.0002
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 18:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1551992400,
            "main": {
                "temp": 34.49,
                "temp_min": 34.49,
                "temp_max": 34.49,
                "pressure": 1025.72,
                "sea_level": 1025.72,
                "grnd_level": 1024.85,
                "humidity": 92,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 804,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "overcast clouds",
                    "icon": "04n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 88
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 3.38,
                "deg": 31.0012
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-07 21:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1552003200,
            "main": {
                "temp": 42.85,
                "temp_min": 42.85,
                "temp_max": 42.85,
                "pressure": 1026.72,
                "sea_level": 1026.72,
                "grnd_level": 1025.83,
                "humidity": 86,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 804,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "overcast clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 88
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 7.49,
                "deg": 72.5035
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-03-08 00:00:00"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.  It may be necessary to modify the code below as it is untested, but it gives you an idea of how to tackle this issue:

```
$previous_date = '';
foreach ($forecastParsed['list'] as $key) {
   $dt_txt = $key['dt_txt'];
   $date = new DateTime($dt_txt);
   $current_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
   if ($current_date != $previous_date) { echo $key['main']['temp']; }
   $previous_date = $current_date;
}
```

It could also be written more concisely (ie. combine first 2 lines within `foreach` to eliminate `$dt_txt` variable).

Explanation of logic:
This `foreach` loop gets the datetime for the current `$key`, strips the timestamp off and puts that into `$current_date`.  Then `$current_date` is compared to `$previous_date`.  If they do not match then we know it's a new day and the temp is echoed.  The `$previous_date` is reset to `$current_date` so the value in that variable is ready for the next loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it works but it still echoes all hours of the days. I only want the first iteration of the result of each day instead of all the hours for each day. For example 3/7/19 i want the first result. 3/8/19 I want the first result and so on.

Comment: Can you edit the original post and add your updated code, a screen shot of the results you're getting and also a mock up of the data you want to get back?

Comment: Actually I got it how I wanted. I modified your code a bit and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic!  Glad you figured it out.